# Is there an eclipse plugin such that task tags can be parameterized?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, comments

I have some TODO tags in my Java code and would like to parameterize them, mainly with

- priorities
- types
- deadlines.

Since I do not want to create new task tags for each combination of these aspects (especially for each deadline), is there a plugin that can handle parameterized TODO tags?

E.g. it should set the task's priority and deadline correctly for

```
\\TODO !1 ^30.11.1999 #Y2kBug...
```

---

Details:

- I know many consider TODO comments as being bad, so you need not explain...
- Parameters in the style of [Remember the milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) would be cool, e.g. `^dueDate` or `!priority`.
- If the eclipse plugin could warn me when the deadline is reached, that would be awesone, since I would no longer need [extra tests as tickler](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestAsTickler).
- Maybe some review tool has a superset of the capabilities I want?
- Sometimes I have a TODO that is a a result of another TODO (i.e. when I fix the first TODO, I will have to fix the other, but it's not really the same TODO/feature). So dependencies between TODOs would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a plugin that does specifically what you ask for but, did you consider adopting a bug tracking tool, even if just for personal use? In this case one tool that does something similar to what you ask, but probably not from within Eclipse, is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/): Its [TracLinks](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks) feature is close to what you need. There is a [Trac/Eclipse bridge](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/EclipseTracPlugin), but it appears not to be developed any more.

An Eclipse based alternative would be to use [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/), possibly together with an external bug tracking tool. However my impression is that [connecting activities with portions of code](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Context) is rather cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mylyn was my first though, but with a quick look into it, my intentioned seemed to not be achievable. I'll look into Trac - what I have wanted to do for a while now anyways.

Comment: Hm, I wonder how dueDate could be implemented: Is there a wiki markup for it? I'd have to generate a milestone for the TODO-field to have a dueDate, right?

Comment: The issue http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/1962 seems to cover deadlines on tasks - does sound a little fiddly, though :(

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of just putting a link to an issue in your TODO comment, and leave all the info within Trac

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [Jupiter](http://code.google.com/p/jupiter-eclipse-plugin/), which is used to add comments to existing code for the purpose of reviewing. I don't know if it will still work if you modify the code, however, as it stores the comments in an XML file indexed by filename and line number.

Comment: Strange, I did find the Eclipse TODO Editor in the Marketplace some time ago, but it seemed to me like an editor for writing a TODO list, not a tool to manage the TODOs you have in your source code. The homepage reads very much so: "It's just a todo list for everyday note-taking". Have you used it already? Can you really manage your source code TODOs with it?

Comment: You're right, I installed it quickly and it is not what you're looking for. You can add custom task tags in Eclipse without a plugin, just go to preferences>java>compiler>task tags, but that won't give you everything you're looking for either.

Comment: Yup, as I've said: Since I do not want to create new task tags for each combination of these aspects (especially for each deadline)...

Comment: Jupiter sounds like a great review tool. Since it does not handle review issues as code comments, but separately, I cannot intertwine it with TODO comments in my source code. Thanks for the effort anyways (+1).